# Mismatched entity andf/or field definitions

Tags: fields

Drupal is giving me an error that looks like the schema is out of date. I've run 'upgrade' and there is no tasks outstanding.

How do I fix these

```
Mismatched entity and/or field definitions
The following changes were detected in the entity type and field definitions.

CiviCRM Activity

  The Is GOTV? field needs to be installed.

CiviCRM Event

  The Is qr code used for this Event? field needs to be installed.

CiviCRM Participant

  The Public key field needs to be installed.
  The QR Event id field needs to be installed.
  The Qr hash code field needs to be installed.
  The QR image url field needs to be installed.
  The Bio field needs to be installed.
```

Comment: These sound like they may relate to one or more extensions. do you have https://civicrm.org/extension-used-for/civicampaign

Comment: I have a similiar problem

Comment: @Ben Tell me if this works - run civi upgrade  https://site/civicrm/upgrade?reset=1. Rebuild all caches (drush cr) Then run drupal update https://site/update.php. Then check the status report https://site/admin/reports/status. Check for entities out of date. If out of date uninstall/reinstall the civicrm entity module. I think this is the module that was the root cause. There is a drush entup https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_entity_updates that is now only recommended for development processes.

Comment: @Interlated - yes worked :) Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Most likely this was caused by the [civicrm entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity) module. To fix

- Check that the CiviCRM database is upgraded https://site/civicrm/upgrade?reset=1.
- Reset the drupal caches *drush cr*
- Run the drupal upgrade https://site/update.php
- Check the drupal status report page https://site/admin/reports/status for entities out of date
- Uninstall the *civicrm_entity* module *drush pm:uninstall civicrm_entity*
- Reinstall *civicrm_entity* *drush en -y civicrm_entity*
- Clear caches again *drush cr*
- Check the status report page again.

There is an [entity updates module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_entity_updates) that may let you run *drush entup* although it is only recommended for development sites.

Comment: Many thanks @Interlated, those stepped worked for me even though I had no upgrades pending. I didn't need to uninstall/re-install CE

Comment: Be very careful about uninstalling and reinstalling CiviCRM entity as I believe it deletes anything you may have done in Drupal (e.g. a View) that uses it!